# ResourceType for MIME-Type: video/*

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mime-types

Which [ResourceType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-ResourceType) do I have to use for the [RequestFilter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-RequestFilter) so that my `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` listener takes up the least amout of resources?

I think it's either `"object"` or `"other"` but I didn't find any information about this.

Because at the moment I use `{urls: ["<all_urls>"]}` to catch all requests and then the code below to check for video requests:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details) {
    details.responseHeaders.forEach(function (header) {
        if (header.name.toLowerCase() === "content-type") {
            var type = header.value.toLowerCase().split('/');
            if (type[0] === "video") {
                type = type[1].split(';')[0];
                alert("Request for " + type + " video registered.");
            }
        }
    });
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(HTML5) video resources are assigned the [ResourceType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-ResourceType) "other".

"object" is used for requests from plugins (loaded via `<embed>` and `<object>`), so if you you want to account for e.g. Flash videos, then you also have to include "object" in your filter.

```
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["other", "object"],
}, ["responseHeaders"]);
```